# Character encoding via JDBC/ODBC/Microsoft Access

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, character-encoding, odbc

I'm doing a connection via JDBC/ODBC to Microsoft Access successfully. After that, I make a query to select rows from Microsoft Access, and I write these results to a TXT file. Everything is OK, but I have some strings that include accents, and these appear as '?' in TXT file. I already tried various forms of methods to write files in java, as PrintWriter, FileWriter, Outputstream, and others, including adding character encoding parameter (UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1) to some these methods. I need any help about some way to show these characters in a right way. Thanks.

Comment: couple of questions, how are you reading the text file? and is the information coming from access correctly?

Comment: @BevynQ Hi. I'm reading the text file by opening it directly. And yes, the information is coming from Microsoft Access correcty, with exception of the characters that appear as '?', because of accents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below line,

```
  String OUTPUTFILE = "PATH/TO/FILE/";
  BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                      new FileOutputStream(OUTPUTFILE),"UTF8"));
```

Once you add that to your code you should be fine using `bf.write('VALUE')` to write `UTF8` characters to your file. And, also make sure to set your text editor encoding to `Unicode` or `UTF8`, if you don't it might seem like the hole process didn't work which would lead to even more confusion.

Edited:

To read UTF8 txts

```
String IPUTFILE = "PATH/TO/File";

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(INPUTFILE), "UTF8"));
```

then to read line `String str = in.readLine();`

Comment: This code not works/write to a file. This is how I put it in my code:

String OUTPUTFILE = "text.txt";

BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(OUTPUTFILE)));
bf.write("a string");


No one character is showed.

Comment: It was missed the bf.close(); I will try again.

Comment: I tried, it showed the string, but yet with characters as "?".

Comment: I saw your comment and you said your reading the file directly, are you reading the file with the proper encoding ? and did you make sure your text editor is setup with the proper encoding as well ?

Comment: How i know if the file is in proper encoding? How you have put in the code, i put the "UTF8" parameter in FileOutputStream.  I'm opening it with notepad++ with UTF-8 encoding, but remains the same "?" characters.

Comment: Well, I just tried to open a file that contains UTF8 characters in notepad++ ( which I don't use at all) and it didn't work. Try a different editor. I use `Sublime Text 2` or `Gedit` works like a charm for me. By the way, I edited my post

Comment: I'm not understanding what are you trying to say, but I did the reading code, according your code you edited. In txt file had a line of string that came from the database, and in this string, in some characters, had "?" characters. So executing your code to read this line, I received the same line that exists/shows if I open the txt file directly by notepad++ in UTF8 encoding.

Comment: I opened with gedit and remains the "?" characters. The java programming that is retrieving the "?" characters.

Comment: @Marco Did you consider the possibility that the text you write to file is already a `?`, because there is a characterset conversion issue before that time (eg between Access and your application).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The text is not with "?" in Access.

I accomplished the procedure successfully with C#/OLEDB connection, no more the characters appears as "?". This way, I solved my problem with other solution, but but I think it would be interesting if this question here still remained active, effectively because the problem was not yet solved this way.

Comment: @Marco Ok, so in access itself it is fine, but did you check the value in Java before you actually write it out.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel
I have checked the value in Java. The characters also appears as "?".